# ArgumentNullException/PlatformNotSupportedException from mscorlib only in debugger

Tags: c#, textbox, mscorlib, argumentnullexception

I have been seeing a pair of exceptions when debugging (VS 2015) which occur when clicking in a Textbox.  They do not always occur but they always seem to occur under the same circumstances (I can't find a pattern which would explain it).  They also only seem to occur once -- if I proceed on, ignoring them, I do not see them happen again.  They also don't seem to be related to a specific Textbox.  My code is a hybrid of existing code and add-on code and the same problem occurs in the code I haven't touched.

I tried creating a very simple project with just a Textbox in a window but I haven't seen the problem there (but again, it doesn't occur in all cases, anyway).

I cannot catch them in a try-catch -- the debugger detects them when they are thrown but it would appear that Microsoft is catching them internally and not throwing out of their code.  If I try running outside the debugger my try-catch catches nothing and the code works with no apparent problems.

The first is a ArgumentNullException thrown by mscorlib.dll.  If I continue after that is thrown, a PlatformNotSupportedException is thrown by PresentationCore.dll.  If I continue after that, my code seems to run fine.

I will put details below but I am wondering, since they appear to be handled internally in Microsoft's code (and seem unrelated to my code) should I just presume it was something I was never intended to see?  If that isn't the case can anyone suggest what might be happening here or how I might debug it?

My platform is Windows 7, I am building with "Any CPU" and the current target framework is .Net 4.5.2 (but I tried it with frameworks up to 4.6.1 with no apparent change).

The initial exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type
  ParamName=type
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(Type type)
  InnerException:
```

A portion of the call stack when this is thrown:

```
mscorlib.dll!System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.WindowsRuntimeMarshal.GetActivationFactory(System.Type type) Line 1279   C#
    PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetWinRtActivationFactory(bool forceInitialization) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.InputPane() Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]  
    PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForWindow(System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source = {System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource})    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.Interop.TipTsfHelper.Show(System.Windows.DependencyObject focusedObject)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.MoveFocusToUiScope(System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor This = {System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor}) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.OnMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(object sender = {System.Windows.Controls.TextBox}, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source = {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}, bool reRaised = false) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender = {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr}, ref bool handled = false)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr}, ref bool handled = false)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr}, ref bool handled = false) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler = null)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr})  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]
```

The mscorlib code throwing the exception (due to a null type parameter) is this:

```
        [SecurityCritical]
        public static IActivationFactory GetActivationFactory(Type type)
        {
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

            if (type.IsWindowsRuntimeObject && type.IsImport)
            {
                return (IActivationFactory)Marshal.GetNativeActivationFactory(type);
            }
            else
            {
#if FEATURE_COMINTEROP_WINRT_MANAGED_ACTIVATION
                return GetManagedActivationFactory(type);
#else 
                // Managed factories are not supported so as to minimize public surface (and test effort)
                throw new NotSupportedException();
#endif
            }
        }
```

If I proceed beyond this exception it throws the following:

```
  System.PlatformNotSupportedException occurred
  HResult=-2146233031
  Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.
  Source=PresentationCore
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane..ctor(Nullable`1 hwnd)
  InnerException:
```

And a partial call stack at that point:

```
PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.InputPane(System.IntPtr? hwnd)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WindowsRuntime.Windows.UI.ViewManagement.InputPane.GetForWindow(System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource source)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.Interop.TipTsfHelper.Show(System.Windows.DependencyObject focusedObject)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.Focus()   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.MoveFocusToUiScope(System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor This = {System.Windows.Documents.TextEditor}) Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Documents.TextEditorMouse.OnMouseDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})    Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.TextBoxBase.OnMouseDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseDownThunk(object sender = {System.Windows.Controls.TextBox}, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(System.Delegate genericHandler, object genericTarget) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(System.Delegate handler, object target)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source = {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs}, bool reRaised = false) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender = {System.Windows.Controls.Grid}, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args = {System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs})  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool trusted) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea() Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(System.Windows.Input.InputEventArgs input)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(System.Windows.Input.InputReport inputReport)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.Windows.Input.InputMode mode, int timestamp, System.Windows.Input.RawMouseActions actions, int x, int y, int wheel)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg = WM_LBUTTONDOWN, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr}, ref bool handled = false)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr}, ref bool handled = false)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr}, ref bool handled = false) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source = {System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher}, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler = null)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd = {System.IntPtr}, int msg = 513, System.IntPtr wParam = {System.IntPtr}, System.IntPtr lParam = {System.IntPtr})  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]  
    [Managed to Native Transition]
```

Proceeding from there, everything runs as expected.

Comment: Are you running the debugger with break on all exceptions?

Comment: @JSteward I'm not sure -- I didn't find that as an option under debugging.  Is it something which is set elsewhere?

Comment: @JSteward I didn't find "break on all exceptions" but I did find the exception settings "Break when thrown".  All exceptions aren't checked in the list but all of the Common Language Runtime Exceptions are checked -- those include both exceptions which were thrown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has vanished after upgrading to Visual Studio 2017.